# Android update LinearLayout in Thread and Runnable

Tags: java, android, json

I'm creating Linear Layout in my application using `LayoutInflater`. The value for this item I'm bring from Jason and I will change the value in run method.

```
public void run() 
{
    /**
    * Updating parsed JSON data into ListView
    **/

    //  coNa .setText(productsList.get(0));
    //  coId.setText(productsList.get(1));
}
```

I created it in `onCreate` function but the application is receiving exception when the value is changed.

```
    @Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.studenttablemain);
     ll = (LinearLayout) findViewById(R.id.ll);



     for (int i=0;i<5;i++){
            View view = LayoutInflater.from(this).inflate(R.layout.studanttableitem,null);

            TextView coNa =  (TextView)findViewById(R.id.coursename);
            TextView coId =  (TextView)findViewById(R.id.courseid);
            TextView teacherid =  (TextView)findViewById(R.id.teachername);
            TextView day =  (TextView)findViewById(R.id.days);
            TextView time =  (TextView)findViewById(R.id.time);
            TextView hole =  (TextView)findViewById(R.id.hole);
            // Assigning value to  imageview and textview here
            ll.addView(view);

}

       new LoadAllProducts().execute();

}






/**
 * Background Async Task to Load all product by making HTTP Request
 * */
class LoadAllProducts extends AsyncTask<String, String, String> {

    /**
     * Before starting background thread Show Progress Dialog
     * */
    @Override
    protected void onPreExecute() {
        super.onPreExecute();
        pDialog = new ProgressDialog(CopyOfstudanttable.this);
        pDialog.setMessage("Loading information . Please wait...");
        pDialog.setIndeterminate(false);
        pDialog.setCancelable(false);
        pDialog.show();
    }

    /**
     * getting All products from url
     * */
    protected String doInBackground(String... args) {
        // Building Parameters
        List<NameValuePair> params = new ArrayList<NameValuePair>();
        // getting JSON string from URL
        JSONObject json = jParser.makeHttpRequest(url_all_products, "GET", params);

        // Check your log cat for JSON reponse
        Log.d("studant: ", json.toString());

        String name="";
        String sid="";
        try {
            // Checking for SUCCESS TAG
            int success = json.getInt(TAG_SUCCESS);

            if (success == 1) {
                // products found
                // Getting Array of Products
                products = json.getJSONArray(TAG_PRODUCTS);

                // looping through All Products
                //for (int i = 0; i < products.length(); i++) {
                    Log.d("length", "-"+products.length()+"-item");

                    JSONObject c = products.getJSONObject(0);

                    // Storing each json item in variable
                    //String id = c.getString(TAG_PID);
                     name = c.getString(TAG_NAME);
                     sid = c.getString(TAG_SID);

                    Log.d("name", "-"+c.getString(TAG_NAME)+"-item");
                    Log.d("id", "-"+c.getString(TAG_SID)+"-item");



                    productsList.add(name);
                    productsList.add(sid);



            //  }
            } else {
                // no products found
                // Launch Add New product Activity
                Intent i = new Intent(getApplicationContext(),
                        LogIn.class);
                // Closing all previous activities
                i.addFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_CLEAR_TOP);
                startActivity(i);
            }
        } catch (JSONException e) {
            e.toString();
            e.printStackTrace();
        }

        return null;
    }

    /**
     * After completing background task Dismiss the progress dialog
     * **/
    protected void onPostExecute(String file_url) {
        // dismiss the dialog once done

        pDialog.dismiss();
        // updating UI from Background Thread
                    runOnUiThread(new Runnable() {
                        public void run() {
                            /**
                             * Updating parsed JSON data into ListView
                             * */

                        //  coNa .setText(productsList.get(0));
                        //  coId.setText(productsList.get(1));


                        }
                    });
    }

}
```

Comment: where is json code??

Comment: what important of json cod 
the result  return in    
    JSONObject c = products.getJSONObject(0);

      // Storing each json item in variable
      //String id = c.getString(TAG_PID);
       name = c.getString(TAG_NAME);
       sid = c.getString(TAG_SID);

Answer (score 1):

You can only change views from the thread that created them, i.e. the ui thread. To change the values from inside another thread you may use for instance `View.post(Runnable)` method. Check this out: [Painless threading](http://android-developers.blogspot.com.by/2009/05/painless-threading.html)

**Update:**
And the method onPostExecute of the AsyncTask already runs on ui thread, so you don't have to invoke runOnUiThread one more time inside of it

```
protected void onPostExecute(String file_url) {
    // dismiss the dialog once done

    pDialog.dismiss();
    //Can set properties right here, cause you are already on Ui thread
    coNa.setText(productsList.get(0));
    coId.setText(productsList.get(1));
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can not update the UI in the sub-thread.You should use a Handler to receive msg from the child thread and update UI.

```
Handler myHandler = new Handler() {  
      public void handleMessage(Message msg) {   
           switch (msg.what) {   
                case 1:   
                      /**
                         * Updating parsed JSON data into ListView
                         * */

                    //  coNa .setText(productsList.get(0));
                    //  coId.setText(productsList.get(1)); 
                     break;   
           }   
           super.handleMessage(msg);   
      }   
 };  

class myThread implements Runnable {   
      public void run() {  
                // get Json data...

                Message message = new Message();   
                message.what = 1;   

                this.myHandler.sendMessage(message);   


      }   
 }
```

My code：

```
private Handler mHandler = new Handler() {

    @Override
    public void handleMessage(Message msg) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        switch (msg.what) {
        case 1:

            if (historyInfos == null) {
                return;
            }

            mAdapter.notifyDataSetChanged();

            break;

        default:
            break;
        }
    }

};

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_call_detail);

    initView();
    initData();
}
```

Comment: json not in run !
 its in  protected String doInBackground(String... args) {

Comment: give me the exception

Comment: in onPostExecute sendMessage to the handler，it's a safe way

Comment: java.lang.NullPointerExceptionat android.app.Activity.runOnUiThread(Activity.java:4673)

Comment: You can put it before onCreate.

Comment: but this create error Multiple markers at this line
 - myHandler cannot be resolved or is not a field
 - Line breakpoint:CopyOfstudanttable$LoadAllProducts [line: 199] 
  - run()

Comment: Don‘t forget : import android.os.Bundle;
   import android.os.Handler;
   import android.os.Message;

Comment: it have the same error    this.myHandler.sendMessage(message);

Comment: (onPostExecute ) where i send message lie in class 
class LoadAllProducts extends AsyncTask<String, String, String> {

but handler you but in CopyOfstudanttable extends Activity{

the on creat method call 
new LoadAllProducts().execute();

Answer (score 0):

You have to move your code below from `doInBackground` to `onPostExecute` method. You should open activities from **uiThread**

```
           // no products found
            // Launch Add New product Activity
            Intent i = new Intent(getApplicationContext(),
                    LogIn.class);
            // Closing all previous activities
            i.addFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_CLEAR_TOP);
            startActivity(i);
```